# Explorer View on the Wiki Section of SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-designer, internet-explorer, wiki-pages, windows-7, explorer-view

Does any one know if you can open a Wiki site page on SharePoint in Explorer View?
If not is there any way around this or will I need to create a new wiki/section to enable me to complete this task?

My computer system is Windows 7 and I am currently using IE 8 to enable me to open Explorer View on other sections.  The only section which won't do it is the Wiki.

Answer (score 0):

"Wiki" can be two things in SharePoint:

- wiki pages in a wiki library
- Enterprise Wiki site

There are many differences between the two, but with regards to "open in [...] Explorer View" both are a resounding "No".

Explorer View can show list columns with some data types like numbers and text.

Wiki pages can have text, images, tables and web parts and other rich elements embedded. A wiki page can contain one or more of each of these elements. These items will not show as columns in an Explorer view.

You need to learn about, and understand, the difference of data types that SharePoint captures. Wiki pages cannot easily be translated into a grid view.

Enterprise Wiki pages are a different chapter altogether. They are a publishing content type, and you will need to understand publishing content types to deal with this data.

**Edit:** You can add custom columns to a wiki library to categorise items. You can then build a view that shows the page title and the category column. Switch to the Data View to bulk edit the page properties.

Comment: Hmm, ok thank you very much for that! Have you found another way to group together your documents on a Wiki site? Because our Team Wiki site is a shambles just now and really needs organising.

Comment: add columns to the library to classify items. I've edited my post with details

Comment: please mark this as the answer if it solves your problem.

Comment: it hasn't solved my problem because I haven't tried it yet

Answer (score 0):

My customers want to open PDFs but somehow the network servers are having an issue (limited to our group unfortunately).  Workaround is to open with explorer but that option is not available in a wiki page.  So that workaround is download, make changes, and upload.  Just an extra step.